# Is there some relation between a task columns: status and the completed?

Tags: tasks

Is there some relation between the task columns "Status" and "Completed" ? I am using 2013. I was wondering if you set the status to "Finished", the completed percentage will be 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but the other Answer is just part of the Answer

All this applies to Language Localized values as well

- `% Complete` is set to 0 when you set the `Status` to `Not Started`
- `% Complete` is set to 100 when you set the `Status` to `Completed`
- `% Complete` is set to 50 when you set the `Status` to **any other value**

This is rather annoying behaviour when you add an extra Status value and do not want the `% Complete` changed.
In our case we added a 'Next Sprint' Status, and we had to add an *On-Change* Workflow to reset the `% Complete` back to 0 for a 'Next Sprint' Status

#### [Completed] is not a regular Calculated Column

It has special code behind it which displays the checkbox

- when checked the `Status` is changed to `Completed` and `% Complete` set to 100
- when unchecked the `Status` is changed to `Not Started` and `% Complete` set to 0

Nowadays with SP2013 this checkbox w/could have been done with CSR - Client Side Rendering.

Note: The `% complete` **value** is actually between 0 and 1; so 50% = 0.5
In case you want to use it in other Calculated Columns

Comment: It is possible configure to when change the status to in progress dont change the % complete?

Comment: No, you would have to override SharePoint code; or not use the Completed field and built you own Checkbox using Client Side Rendering

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `% Complete` and `Task Status` columns in a Tasks list are related.

If you set the `% Complete` column from 0 to 50%, the `Task Status` will change from Not Started to In Progress. If you then set it to 100% the status will change to Completed.

This works the other way as well. If you set the `Task Status` from Not Started to Complete, the `% Complete` column will change to 100%.

Comment: Why do I have a task list where there is no relation between these 2 columns? Was this relation also in sp 2010?

Comment: Not sure why. If this is a specific problem for you submit another question to get exposure. I can't speak for 2010, I haven't really ever used it.

Comment: Also worth noting, when changing `% Complete`, the status is not programmed to change to `Not Started`, `In Progress` or `Completed`, but their respective index in the default choices. That is to say, if you changed the order of these statuses in any way, e.g. by adding an additional status before `Not Started` or moving `Deferred` before `Completed`, SharePoint keeps using the 1st status as `Not Started`, the 2nd as `In Progress` and the 3rd as `Completed`.