# Change task %complete connection to status

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2019

I am fairly new to Sharepoint so I do not have the entire overview of how things work yet.

My problem is as follows.
When I change the %complete field on a task to, e.g., 100% the status change to one called "32 - Ready for review". Changing the status afterward to "90 - Closed" changes the %complete to 50%. When a task is "90 - Closed" the status should be 100%.
I suspect that there is some kind of relationship between %complete field and the status field, but I am however not able to find this connection/relationship.

I have looked at workflows and found out that non are active.

I hope that some are able to give some pointers to how to change the relationship between the two fields.

EDIT:
I have fiddled around with naming and for reasons unknown, it seems that the "Completed" status will always be the third status from the top. Is there some kind of rule for why the "%complete" always chooses the third status from the top? and is it possible to change this rule somehow? or is the rule just set in stone and is the way of Sharepoint?

In an ideal scenario, the statuses would be as shown on the following image, with the "Completed"/"90 - Closed" status not being third from the top. I could change the order of the statuses but that would not make sense from a visual/user experience standpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **% Complete** and **Task Status** columns in a Tasks list are related.

From my research, the default options for **Task Status** in the SharePoint Task list are:

- Not Started
- In Progress
- Completed
- Deferred
- Waiting on someone else

[image]

The Task list has some specific task management “smart” functionality. For example:

- By marking Task Status to Completed, it changes % Complete to 100%.
  And vice versa, by changing % Complete to 100%, it changes Task
  Status to Completed.
- If you set the % Complete column from 0 to 50%, the Task Status will
  change from Not Started to In Progress. If you then set it to 100%
  the status will change to Completed.
- This works the other way as well. If you set the Task Status from Not
  Started to Complete, the % Complete column will change to 100%.

Therefore, we suggest that you can set the options in the Task Status to the following style：

[image]

**Here is a similar case for your reference:**

- [Is there some relation between a task columns: status and the
  completed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/is-there-some-relation-between-a-task-columns-status-and-the-completed)

Comment: I have added some additional information in the original post, and I hope that you are able to answer some of the questions. I know it might not be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The "Completed" will always be the third option from [Status]. This may be caused by the pre-set rule logic inside SharePoint. This problem is hard to troubleshot this issue via community, we suggest you open a ticket from Microsoft for further help.